# Windows 7 Start Menu: "Search programs and files"

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

In Windows 7, after pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, you can type keywords to search for programs. How does Windows 7 determine the order of the search results? Sometimes it seems depends on the frequency you execute the program. Sometimes it just never changes the order.

I wish it could sort by 'most frequently used'. Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. Although not directly addressing Windows 7 the following post gives some information regarding this.

[Designing search for the Start screen](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102123610/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/18/designing-search-for-the-start-screen.aspx)