# Windows 10: where do items in the "Search programs and files" box come from?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

NB this question [Windows 7 Start Menu: "Search programs and files"](https://superuser.com/questions/365797/windows-7-start-menu-search-programs-and-files) is only asking about the **order** of these items.

First point: I am a mouse-hater.  I am not interested either in bringing up the "Start menu"... by far the most efficient way (IMHO) of starting up an app or a document of some kind is to type the first few letters and then select from the filter menu (if applicable).

This works for lots of programs and documents... mostly, though, I have had to add shortcuts to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu.

What I'd *like* is to be able to add a particular directory (e.g. I have a directory called "sysadmin"), so that by default this "Search programs and files" box goes looking for stuff there as well as anywhere else.

I'm aware M$ couldn't give a flying flick about what people may or may not like (NB I use Linux whenever humanly possible), but does anyone know whether this is possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sort of answer/workaround to this which will perhaps suit people who are annoyed as I am at not having the option of just pressing start, entering a couple of letters and launching a document.  Others may find it too much of a rigmarole.

The key here is the "Start Menu" directory.  On my sys this is at "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu".

If you put a shortcut to **an app** here, e.g. named *Gremlin.exe - Shortcut*, you'll find that you can then run it with the initial letters:

```
<Start button>gre....
```

However, putting a shortcut for a **file** does **not** work, not on my system anyway.

What I've done is this

1) first you have to get hold of a freeware utility app called **[hstart64.exe](http://www.initdll.de/hstart64.exe/m-download-74599.html)**, and put it somewhere on your PATH (I put it, and all the things below, in a directory I've made called "SysAdmin"). Google for an *hstart32.exe* for 32-bit machines, I think there is one.

2) then make a shortcut of the file you want to open, and put it in SysAdmin.  Let's say the name of this shortcut is *Myfile.docx - Shortcut*.

3) then make a .bat file in SysAdmin, e.g. *myfile.bat*, containing just the following line (don't forget the quotes):

```
"Myfile.docx - Shortcut"
```

4) then make a shortcut of this .bat file, and move it to the "Start Menu" directory.

5) then edit this shortcut as follows (don't omit quotes):

```
Target: "D:\My Documents\[...]\sysadmin\hstart64.exe" /NOCONSOLE "myfile.bat"

Start in: "D:\My Documents\[...]\sysadmin"
```

6) then rename this shortcut to sthg like *edit myfile* (or you could just rename it *myfile* - up to you).

you should then be able to launch this by going

```
<Start button>edit my...
```

No doubt there are other possibilities for entering the filename as, for example, a parameter passed to the .bat file.  But for me this is all about opening half a dozen files which I'm constantly opening...  ***with minimal keystrokes***.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I'd like is to be able to add a particular directory

1. Start "Control Panel" > Indexing Options"

   [image]
2. Click "Modify"

   [image]
3. Browse to the directory sysadmin and enable the check box.

   [image]
4. Click "OK".

Notes:

> - If you don't see all locations on your computer in the list, click "Show all locations". (If all locations are listed, "Show all
>     locations" won't be available.)
> - If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> - If you want to include a folder but not all of its subfolders, click the folder, and then clear the check box next to any subfolder
>     that you don't want to index. These folders will appear in the
>     "Exclude" column of the Summary of selected locations list.

Source: Click "How does indexing affect searches" on the first dialog.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Unfortunately it's not working for me... in fact it turns out that I **had** already managed to add the directory in question using this mechanism.  But there's (for example) a file in \sysadmin called runDocManager.bat ... but when I enter that in the "Search programs and files" box it doesn't find it.  The years have taught me resilience in the fact of this sort of thing: this is a not atypical M$ experience: broken broken broken.

Answer (score 1):

One source is the `PATH` system variable.

I just create a folder containing all the shortcuts to my favourite tools and add this folder to system variable `PATH`. Then I can access those tools by inputing the shortcut names in Start Menu.